# Помощь с решением задачи

Tags: c#, .net

Задача такова: у нас есть переменная типа `string`, в которой записаны самые высокие здания мира и длина каждого. У меня есть функция, которая принимает на вход эту переменную. Мне нужно убрать из текста этой переменной названия всех башен то есть все буквенные символы, оставить только длины зданий то есть числовые символы и в этих числовых символах оставить только первые цифры. Затем мне нужно посчитать количество вхождений каждой цифры в данной переменной. Цифр девять от 1 до 9. Далее мне нужно записать количество вхождений каждой цифры в массив длиной 10 символов. То есть к примеру в индексе `0` мне нужно записать число `0` так как ни одно число в тексте не начинается на эту цифру, а вот в индексе `1` мне нужно записать число `24` так как цифра `1` встречается в тексте именно такое количество раз. И таким образом нужно заполнить весь массив. В итоге должно получиться так: `0, 24, 9, 8, 6, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1`

Вот мой код:
[image]

Моя проблема в том, что я не знаю каким образом заполнить массив `statistics` Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать. И да, я допускаю, что в моем коде могут присутствовать ошибки. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Текст программы добавляйте в виде текста. Картинку неудобно компилировать.

Comment: На каких входных данных это должно получиться? `0, 24, 9, 8, 6, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1`

Comment: Вставьте пожалуйста ко текстом

Comment: Поставил минус за: 1. Код картинкой 2. Отсутствие примера входных данных

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам в тексте надо найти каждое число (а в тексте только целые числа), взять первую его цифру и посчитать по этим цифрам статитику, вот простейший пример

```
int[] GetFirstDigitStats(string input)
{
    var ret = new int[10];
    int ind = 0;
    
    while(ind < input.Length)
    {
        while(ind < input.Length && !char.IsDigit(input[ind])) ind++;
        if (ind < input.Length) ret[input[ind] - '0']++;
        while(ind < input.Length && char.IsDigit(input[ind])) ind++;
    }   
    
    return ret;
}
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", GetFirstDigitStats("building one 122 builing two 444 building three 111")));
```

Результат

```
0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
```

Если вам надо по всем цифрам статистику, вот пример ещё проще

```
int[] GetDigitStats(string input)
{
    var ret = new int[10];
    for(int i=0; i<input.Length; i++)
     if (char.IsDigit(input[i])) ret[input[i] - '0']++;
    return ret;
}
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", GetDigitStats("building one 122 builing two 444 building three 111")));
```

Результат

```
0,4,2,0,3,0,0,0,0,0
```